# DataGridView resets to top when clicked after mouse scroll

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataGridView control on a TabPage of a Windows Form application.

When the user moves the mouse over the DataGrid and uses the scroll wheel, the grid scrolls as expected. But when the user clicks in a cell on the screen, instead of the cell receiving focus, the DataGrid resets to the top and requires the user to scroll down again. This response is non-intuitive since it's not immediately obvious that the cell you thought you clicked on isn't there anymore.

I would be happy to prevent the DataGrid from responding to the scroll wheel until the user clicks in the grid, or preferably to maintain the current actions except not resetting to the top when first clicked.

From what I've researched here, it appears that the DataGrid is rebinding because I'm resetting the binding when the tabpage is entered (since the database might have been updated by one of the other tabs.

```
Private Sub TabPage1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabPage1.Enter
        LoadTACTable()
    End Sub
```

In `LoadTACTable()`:

```
dbGetList("spSelectTACList", dtTACs, 0, 100000, Nothing)  ' Record numbers are 0 based
        bsTACs.DataSource = dtTACs
        With gridTACs
            ' TOTAL Grid width = 1380
            .DataSource() = bsTACs
            .
            .
            .
```

(Showing only part of the code for brevity.

Is there a way to see if the TabPage is already displayed when entered? Or, is unnecessary to reset the `gridTAC` datasource every time I retrieve the data from the SQL database to the `dtTACs` datatable using my `dbGetList()` sub?

Comment: The cell is receiving focus, but you're telling the form to remove all the current data, which removes that cell, and then display new data.  You should do some reading on the `TabControl` and determine which event you should actually be handling, because it's not the `Enter` event of a `TabPage`.

Comment: I'd also question whether it should be necessary to update the data at all.  A lot of people do things backwards and make life difficult for themselves as a result.  Rather than having each tab interacting independently with the database, it may be better to just have one `DataSet` for the form that contains all the data locally.  If multiple tabs are using the same data then any changes made by one will automatically be reflected in the other.  This may not be possible if you're dealing with a lot of data and can't cache it all locally but it's preferable if you can do it.

Comment: Caching the data locally is not ideal since the database can be accessed by multiple clients and I would have far more contention problems. I also dislike asking the user to click a "refresh" button, as I think that's a clumsy UX.

I do think I solved the problem by creating a Boolean flag to indicate the tabs are "dirty" then setting it in the `TabPage.Leave` handler. I'm doing a little more testing to be sure.

Comment: In that case, this is a spurious statement: *"since the database might have been updated by one of the other tabs"*. If the database might have been updated by other users, whether it is updated by other tabs is rather moot.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions to your problem. One would be to not automatically rebind the datagrid but let the user do it by clicking some refresh button. That way the user would not see non-intuitive behavior.

You mentioned that the contents of one tab may need to be refreshed when the contents of other tabs are changed. Whenever the contents of a tab is changed and can affect other tabs, you could flag these other tabs (for example, by adding a star to their titles) to indicate that they no longer have the latest data. The user would then know that the tab needs to be refreshed.

There might be other solutions, but it is difficult to tell without knowing more about your use case.

Answer (score 0):

With the guidance above, I believe I solved the issue:

I created a flag:

`Dim TabDirty As Boolean`

Then I set it in the `TabPage.Leave` handler:

```
Private Sub TabPage1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabPage1.Leave
        dtTACs.Dispose()
        TabDirty = True
    End Sub
```

Then I just check it when I enter the TabPage:

```
Private Sub TabPage1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabPage1.Enter
        If TabDirty = True Then
            TabDirty = False
            LoadTACTable()
        End If
    End Sub
```

So far, this appears to work - the grid is not getting reset when clicked, but I will do a bit more testing to confirm that the data is refreshed when necessary.